# Sorting within a group

Tags: sql, sorting, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables: `Items` and `Categories`. Each item belongs to a category.

**Table Items**

```
║ Item_name ║ Category_id ║ Price ║

║ A         ║ Cat_1    ║ 100   ║

║ B         ║ Cat_1    ║ 50    ║

║ C         ║ Cat_2    ║ 98    ║

║ D         ║ Cat_2    ║ 99    ║

║ E         ║ Cat_1    ║ 40    ║
```

**Table Categories**

```
║ Category_id ║ Category_name ║

║ Cat_1       ║ X             ║

║ Cat_2       ║ Y             ║
```

I want to sort all items within a category by price. How can I do that? Expected outcome:

```
║ Item_name ║ Category ║ Price ║

║ E         ║ Cat_1    ║ 40    ║

║ B         ║ Cat_1    ║ 50    ║

║ A         ║ Cat_1    ║ 100   ║

║ C         ║ Cat_2    ║ 98    ║

║ D         ║ Cat_2    ║ 99    ║
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your expected results, you don't even need the categories table. Simply select from the items table in the desired order.

```
SELECT i.Item_Name, i.Category_ID, i.Price
    FROM items i
    ORDER BY i.Category_ID, i.price;
```

But should you want to include the category name, a simple join will do.

```
SELECT i.Item_Name, i.Category_ID, c.Category_Name, i.Price
    FROM items i
        INNER JOIN categories c
            ON i.Category_ID = c.Category_ID
    ORDER BY i.Category_ID, i.price;
```

**EDIT**
Based on the question in the comment, how to return the 50 cheapest items in each category for SQL Server. You can use a common table expression (CTE) and leverage the ROW_NUMBER function to number the items within each category by price.

```
WITH cteOrderByCategory AS (
    SELECT i.item_name, i.Category_ID, i.price,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY i.Category_ID ORDER BY i.price) AS RowNum
        FROM items i
)
SELECT obc.item_name, obc.Category_ID, obc.price
    FROM cteOrderByCategory obc
    WHERE obc.RowNum <= 50
    ORDER BY obc.Category_ID, obc.price;
```

Comment: Thank you Joe! If I wanted to only get the cheapest 50 items in each category, how could I place that restriction?

Comment: @Akshay: What RDBMS are you using (e.g., MySQL, SQL Server)?

Comment: I am using SQL server. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Joe! I am trying it out now.

Answer (score 1):

No need to group, you only need to order:

```
select
    i.Item_Name,
    c.Category_name,
    i.Price
from items i
    inner join Categories c on i.category_id = c.category_id
order by c.category_id, i.price
```